# How the event loop works under the hood?

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

I started digging into how event loop works in depth. I understand that it is run in a single thread for I/O operations(networks) except of working with files. Read about phases in libuv. But I can't understand how callbacks/handles are put in those libuv queues. For example I make http request and pass a callback and the question is: where the request is actually being processed, since libuv listens for the events(kind of: got response), who emits these events? Is it handled by OS?

I think I have misunderstanding of this topic but I really can't figure out where to find an answer, what should I start reading, etc... Thanks.

Comment: [The Node.js Event Loop, Timers and and process.nextTick](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

Comment: @James I don't how it works, but the answer is in the first paragraph... <<The event loop is what allows Node.js to perform non-blocking I/O operations by *offloading operations to the system kernel* whenever possible.>>. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

It is really simple. The answer is in the first paragraph of https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/. Thanks to @James for getting me read this doc attentively.